# Bean order when autowired into list

Tags: java, spring, autowired, applicationcontext, spring-bean

I have defined an interface `IWorker` and some implementations of it as `WorkerA` and `WorkerB`, both annotated with `@Component`.

I then autowire them into my app via:

```
@Autowired
private List<IWorker> workers = new ArrayList<IWorker>();
```

- From what does the order the workers are put into the list depend on?
- How can I let additional `WorkerC` and `WorkerD` (also implementations of `IWorker`) not annotated with `@Component` be autowired into the same list via my `applicationContext.xml`?
- Is the order of `WorkerC` and `WorkerD` from the xml preserved?
- Is there a rule I can rely on in which order worker A, B, C and D will be put into the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to order these dependencies in the List injected by Spring, then use @Order annotation.